# Show alert based on each condition

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have several conditions from backend
iI want to print an alert based on the condition in antd modal like,

```
Modal.confirm({
  centered: true,
  title:
    'Sorry, you cannot create Menu without satisfying  the following conditions: \n\n  name\n nameclass \n ageover, \n numberclass.',
  okText: 'okay',
  cancelText: 'cancel',
  onOk: () => {
    this.props.setForm('');
  },
});
```

But need show the required fields in the title is based on the data from backend. like,

`res.data={ nameval: 'jan', group:null, numberclass:5, ageover:21}`

so required field to show as based on this result is group. If

`res.data={ nameval:'', group:null, numberclass:0, ageover:0}`

in this need to show each condition in modal. How to check each condition availability from res.data and show the modal alert baased on that requirment. If we set if else need to write t0o many probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in return statement

```
fetch(url).then(data =>{
   return Modal.confirm({
            centered: true,
            title:data.title,
            okText: 'okay',
            cancelText: 'cancel',
            onOk: () => {
               this.props.setForm('');
            },
         });
})
```

Comment: it is not like this I want

Comment: Can you share the whole code?